# How to add more than one listener to a drilldown pieChart in amCharts

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener, amcharts

I'm working with highcharts and amCharts, but I'm stuck in this little thing.

So, I have a drilldown piechart made with amCharts, like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

But I wanted another feature! After "drilling-down", I would like to select one particular combination and navigate to another page (where I would give some information to the user concerning such combination...)

So, click once in pie chart => go to subtypes. Click again in a subtype => go to a page of my choosing!

I've tried using this answer, but somehow it does not work with this drilling down feature!

```
// add click listener
  chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", handleClick);
```

I'm a bit lost, is this because the drill down already uses a addListener? Can you give me a hand, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
chart.addListener("clickSlice", function (event) {
    // if dataItem.dataContext.id, this is the 
    // event before drillDown
    if (event.dataItem.dataContext.id != undefined) {
        selected = event.dataItem.dataContext.id;
    }
    else { // click event on subtypes after drilldown occurs
        selected = undefined;
        // PUT YOUR CODE HERE
    }
    chart.dataProvider = generateChartData();
    chart.validateData();
});
```